# VB.NET Page reloads every time I mark a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I prevent the page from reloading when ever I click on a checkbox?
This can be cumbersome when I have hundreds of checkboxes.
Below is my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(ImagePath)
    Dim imageArray As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim image As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all images in the specified directory

    For Each image In imageArray.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Name)
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="table" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="vertical" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I believe I set AutoPostBack=True because of the below code:

```
Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    For count As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckBoxList1.Items(count).Selected Then
            File.Delete(ImagePath & CheckBoxList1.Items(count).ToString)
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Remove(count)
        End If
    Next

    Response.Redirect("Delete.aspx")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set AutoPostBack to False to prevent the page from reloading. Then depends on what you are trying to do with the checkbox after doing that change.

Answer (score 7):

You have `AutoPostBack="True"`. Set it to `False` if you don't want it to automatically post back.